# Plotting Idealized Blackbody Spectra

Tags: python, numpy, physics, astropy, astronomy

So I am getting a couple errors

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
intensity = a/ ( (wav**5) * (np.exp(b) - 1.0) )
```

and

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
intensity = a/ ( (wav**5) * (np.exp(b) - 1.0) )
```

Even with these errors (and one more about dividing by zero that I ignore lol) my graph gets produced correctly either way. I am just wondering if anyone can help me clear up these errors? Please and thanks.

Here is the full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy import constants as const


def planck(T, wav):
    a = 2.0*h*c**2
    b = h*c/(wav*k*T)
    intensity = a/ ( (wav**5) * (np.exp(b) - 1.0) )
    return intensity

# Part 1: Plotting Planck's Law

T1 = 3750
T2 = 5200
T3 = 9600 # Temperature of M0 star, the Sun, and A0 star (K)
c = const.c.value
h = const.h.value
k = const.k_B.value
l = np.linspace(0, 1.5e-6, 1500) #Array of wavlengths (meters)
IM0 = planck(T1, l) 
Isun = planck(T2, l)
IA0 = planck(T3, l) # Planck's law intensities 

plt.figure(1) # Plot of the three idealized blackbody spectra
plt.plot(l, IM0, 'k-', label = 'M0 Star')
plt.plot(l, Isun, 'r--', label = 'Sun')
plt.plot(l, IA0, 'b-.', label = 'B0')
plt.xlabel('Wavelength (meters)')
plt.ylabel('Intensity (W sr^{-1} m^{-3})')
plt.title('Idealized Blackbody Spectra')
#plt.legend('M0 Star', 'Sun', 'B0 Star')
leg = plt.legend()
plt.ticklabel_format(axis="x", style="sci", scilimits=(0,0)) # Scientific not
```

Comment: See also my answer on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61489942/getting-error-can-only-apply-exp-function-to-dimensionless-quantities-not-s).  You may be getting into hot water by not using the correct units.  Try sticking with giving units to all your quantities as it will help ensure your calculations are all correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First 5 values of `l` are too small, which causes high values of `b` and thus a numerical overflow in `exp` (as exp(1500) is just a very large number).

In fact, the first value in `l` is simply zero, and thus `wav` in `planck()` becomes infinite and `1/wav**5` is NaN.

Hence all the warnings. Set `l = np.linspace(6e-9, 1.5e-6, 1500)` and you'll be fine.

And no, [index](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10765801/index), it is not IDE warning, it's Python warning. There are ways to suppress such warnings, but you can only do that once you know exactly what are you suppressing and why.

Comment: That cleared it up! Also helped me on my next task! Thank you!